# AngularJS w/ noscript

Tags: angularjs, noscript

I am attempting to create a SPA using AngularJS as the main view for my website. I'm using ServiceStack on the server-side and can therefore cleanly serve HTML or JSON requests depending on what's accessing it. My main concern is the use of script blockers, preventing AngularJS from rendering the page properly. So far my main way of working is to render static pages, and inject a small script that redirects to the AngularJS-powered pages if it detects if Javascript is enabled. This works great since every URL works fine when the user begins at the static pages, but I've ran into a couple of snags.

1. Browsing to a link which includes the "?View=SPA" breaks the page if JavaScript is disabled
2. This causes the first page loaded to be loaded twice.

I'm looking for an alternative, but so far I haven't found any clean solutions. I was thinking about including the "?View=SPA" as a POST variable, but I'm still iffy on that implementation.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you just include a <noscript> tag in your main page? Something like:
<noscript>
    <h1>Unfortunately your browser has disabled scripting. Please enable it in order to display this page.</h1>
</noscript>
So, rather than redirecting to your AngularJS page if you've detected that Javascript is enabled, just include the <noscript> in your main SPA page.

Comment: Well, I still want something functional for those without Javascript. Even though that population is small, I don't want to shut out potential clients that way.

Comment: You haven't selected an answer. If you found a better solution than the others below, could you post it as an answer?  I'm curious about a good approach to this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of redirecting to an other page, I would implement both cases in the same HTML File as follows:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style>.hideIfNoScript {display: none}</style>
  </head>
  <body ng-app ng-init="msg = 'hello world'">
    <input class="hideIfNoScript" ng-model="msg" />
    <p class="hideIfNoScript">{{msg}}</p>
    <noscript>
        <p>Content without javascript</p>
    </noscript>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelectorAll( '.hideIfNoScript' ) );
        myEl.removeClass('hideIfNoScript');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSS Class hideIfNoScript in the head section makes sure that all HTML Tags with this class are never shown to the user, if javascript is disabled.

The noscript tag shows the alternative content.

If javascript is enabled, the little script at the **end** of the body section makes those elements visible. And in this case, the contents of the noscript tag are hidden.

Comment: What about getting that content in the noscript tag, are we supposed to make an ajax call on the server to get that content?

Comment: @AyexeM: Since the browser shows the content within the noscript tag only when javascript is disabled or unavailable, it would not be possible to make any AJAX calls anyway. You can put only static HTML Code here.

Answer (score 0):

> Browsing to a link which includes the "?View=SPA" breaks the page if JavaScript is disabled

Hide those links by default:

```
a[href*='SPA'] { display: none; }
```

> This causes the first page loaded to be loaded twice

Use a cookie on a [browser-check page](http://www.informit.com/articles/printerfriendly/677911) which loads the first page in an iframe or redirects to it to avoid this.

**References**

[Track Non-JavaScript Visits In Google Analytics](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/track-non-javascript-visits-google-analytics/)